# How to Hide the TabPager Layout with Animation

Tags: android, animation

im tryin to hid my Tabs layous with an animation, here i provided a code, but it only works on the titles of the Tabs, so im Forced to Hide the Tab manually, is there Any way that I Can Hide the Tabs Layout With Animation?

```
        tabs.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                int positionOffsetPixels) {
            if(position == 3){             
                System.out.println("position:"+position);
                if(badge2!=null){
                    badge2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    badge2.invalidate();
                    badge2=null;
                }
                TranslateAnimation anim = new  
  TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0,-100);             
                anim.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
                anim.setDuration(1000);
                tabAnimation=anim;
            tabs.setAnimation(anim);
```

Answer (score 0):

ok found the solution, instead of tabs, used the Animation on the ViewPager